# Convert Hexadecimal String to Base64 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, hex, base64

Is there a way to convert a hexadecimal string to base64 in Swift? For example, I would like to convert:

```
BA5E64C0DE
```

to:

```
ul5kwN4=
```

It's possible to convert a normal string to base64 by using:

```
let hex: String = "BA5E64C0DE"

let utf8str: NSData = hex.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64Encoded: NSString = utf8str.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

let base64: String = (base64Encoded as String)
```

But this would give a result of:

```
QkE1RTY0QzBERQ==
```

Because it's just treating the hex as a normal UTF-8 String, and not hexadecimal.

It's possible to convert it to base64 correctly by looping through every six hex characters and converting it to it's four respective base64 characters, but this would be highly inefficient, and is just plain stupid (there would need to be **17,830,160** if statements):

```
if(hex == "000000"){base64+="AAAA"}
else if(hex == "000001"){base64+="AAAB"}
else if(hex == "000002"){base64+="AAAC"}
else if(hex == "BA5E64"){base64+="ul5k"}
//...
```

It would be nice if there was something like this:

```
let hex: String = "BA5E64C0DE"

let data: NSData = hex.dataUsingEncoding(NSHexadecimalEncoding)!
let base64Encoded: NSString = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

let base64: String = (base64Encoded as String)
```

But sadly, there's no `NSHexadecimalEncoding`. Is there any efficient way to convert a hexadecimal string to it's base64 representation in Swift?

Comment: I've seen this down-vote pattern before (rapid downvote of question and all answers rapidly, but without a single explanation why) and it's quite tiresome. Perhaps they thought this was all duplicative of other discussions (though I think it's slightly different, even though it touches on issues well-covered elsewhere). I dunno. Did I answer your question, though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base-64 string, `"ul5kwN4="`, translates to a binary `NSData` consisting of of five bytes `BA`, `5E`, `64`, `C0`, and `DE`.

Now, if you really had a string with the hexadecimal representation, you could convert it to a binary `NSData` using a routine like the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502285/1271826

Once you have a `NSData`, you could build your base 64 string:

```
let hexString = "BA5E64C0DE"
let binaryData = hexString.dataFromHexadecimalString()
let base64String = binaryData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
```

That generates the desired output, `ul5kwN4=`.

Comment: @Jojodmo I notice you changed your example. I changed my implementation and confirmed I'm getting the desired base64 string.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work. May I suggest adding the full code to this answer instead of linking to another answer? ([here's the code I used](http://i.gyazo.com/8dfb1222de9ed0688b4e395bf113b6f1.png))

Comment: is it possible to convert base 64 to hexadecimal string

Comment: @BraneDullet - Just reverse the process, creating a `Data`/`NSData` from the string (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410081-init) and then, if you really need a hexadecimal string representation of that, use the `hexadecimal()` method in [that other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26502285/1271826).

Comment: @Rob, what is swift 3 alternative?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj - The Swift 3 rendition is at the end of the linked Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 2):

1. First, convert `Hex String` to `Data` using the following routine. (Worked in **Swift 3.0.2**)

   ```
   extension String {
       /// Expanded encoding
       ///
       /// - bytesHexLiteral: Hex string of bytes
       /// - base64: Base64 string
       enum ExpandedEncoding {
           /// Hex string of bytes
           case bytesHexLiteral
           /// Base64 string
           case base64
       }

       /// Convert to `Data` with expanded encoding
       ///
       /// - Parameter encoding: Expanded encoding
       /// - Returns: data
       func data(using encoding: ExpandedEncoding) -> Data? {
           switch encoding {
           case .bytesHexLiteral:
               guard self.characters.count % 2 == 0 else { return nil }
               var data = Data()
               var byteLiteral = ""
               for (index, character) in self.characters.enumerated() {
                   if index % 2 == 0 {
                       byteLiteral = String(character)
                   } else {
                       byteLiteral.append(character)
                       guard let byte = UInt8(byteLiteral, radix: 16) else { return nil }
                       data.append(byte)
                   }
               }
               return data
           case .base64:
               return Data(base64Encoded: self)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then, convert `Data` to `Base64 String` using `Data.base64EncodedString(options:)`.

---

**Usage**

```
let base64 = "BA5E64C0DE".data(using: .bytesHexLiteral)?.base64EncodedString()
if let base64 = base64 {
    print(base64)
    // Prints "ul5kwN4="
}
```