# How do I convert an NSData object with hex data to ASCII in Swift?

Tags: ios, string, swift, hex, nsdata

I have an `NSData` object with hex data and I want to convert it to an ASCII string. I've seen several similar questions to mine but they are all either in Objective-C and/or they convert a string into hex data instead of the other way around.

I found [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793595/how-do-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-its-unicode-ascii-equivalent-in-swift) but it doesn't work in Swift 2 and the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Strideable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs10Strideable) doesn't explain the difference between the old `stride` and the new `stride` (it doesn't explain stride at all):

```
func hex2ascii (example: String) -> String
{

    var chars = [Character]()

    for c in example.characters
    {
        chars.append(c)
    }

    let numbers =  stride(from: 0, through: chars.count, by: 2).map{ // error: 'stride(from:through:by:)' is unavailable: call the 'stride(through:by:)' method instead.
        strtoul(String(chars[$0 ..< $0+2]), nil, 16)
    }

    var final = ""
    var i = 0

    while i < numbers.count {
        final.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(numbers[i]))))
        i++
    }

    return final
}
```

I don't know what `stride` is and I don't know what it does.

How do you convert hex to ASCII in Swift 2? Maybe an NSData extension...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I just (accidentally) found an amazing solution to my problem and hopefully this will help someone.

If you have an NSData object with a hex representation of an ASCII string, then all you have to do is write `String(data: theNSDataObject, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` and that is the ASCII string.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
let asciiString = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
print(asciiString)
```

Comment: I like this answer as an option because it was successfully able to handle a situation in which the solution selected by Jake //namely: `String(data: theNSDataObject, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` // was generating output that sometimes failed a screen for "valid" utf-8 sequences when I only needed ascii characters.  Note:  Swift 3.0.2, Xcode 8.2, prefers (instead of encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding):  `let asciiString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)`

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2.0 stride became a method on Int rather than a standalone method so now you do something like

```
0.stride(through: 10, by: 2)
```

So now the code you posted should be:

```
func hex2ascii (example: String) -> String {
    var chars = [Character]()

    for c in example.characters {
        chars.append(c)
    }

    let numbers =  0.stride(through: chars.count, by: 2).map{
        strtoul(String(chars[$0 ..< $0+2]), nil, 16)
    }

    var final = ""
    var i = 0

    while i < numbers.count {
        final.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(numbers[i]))))
        i++
    }

    return final
}
```