# NSKeyedArchiver sometimes makes a broken file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

My iOS app saves NSCoding objects in Document directory.
NSKeyedArchiver archives them. It is always O.K. but sometimes makes broken files.

The broken files have the following two patterns.

- Lack of data

  - I can convert them to ascii strings and recover meaningful

    - [How do I convert an NSData object with hex data to ASCII in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007247/how-do-i-convert-an-nsdata-object-with-hex-data-to-ascii-in-swift)
  - They have bplist prefix.  But they don’t have the trailers.
- Total loss

  - I cannot convert them to ascii strings.
  - They look shifting all bytes.

This is one of the headers in the broken files comparing with the correct header.

broken (sequence of characters seems to be different every data):

```
  Nè\à¡<99>K<80>^_È<97>▸T§:Æñã9µú▸Ñ1^LË^VYGfM^A%KÍ<95
```

expected:

```
  bplist00Ô^A^B^C^D^E^H01T$topX$objectsX$versionY$
```

Has anyone experience the same case?