# How to crypt string to sha1 in base64 with Swift?

Tags: php, ios, swift, base64, hmacsha1

I want to crypt privateKey & publicKey to sha1 in base64 with Swift, but the output is not the one I see in PHP urlencode base64_encode which I tried in Codecademy:"https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/3?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8".

Pls see the following codes in Swift and Codecademy:

**Swift:**

```
//pls see func dataFromHexadecimalString() details here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501276/convert-string-to-hex-string-in-swift/26502285#26502285" 

extension String {

func dataFromHexadecimalString() -> NSData? {
    let trimmedString = self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<> ")).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

    var error: NSError?
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9a-f]*$", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
    let found = regex?.firstMatchInString(trimmedString, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(trimmedString)))
    if found == nil || found?.range.location == NSNotFound || count(trimmedString) % 2 != 0 {
        return nil
    }

    let data = NSMutableData(capacity: count(trimmedString) / 2)

    for var index = trimmedString.startIndex; index < trimmedString.endIndex; index = index.successor().successor() {
        let byteString = trimmedString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: index, end: index.successor().successor()))
        let num = UInt8(byteString.withCString { strtoul($0, nil, 16) })
        data?.appendBytes([num] as [UInt8], length: 1)
    }

    return data
  }
}

func URLEcodekey() -> String {
    let appid="a1b2c34d5e"
    let privateKey="ef7d6s0d"
    let areaid="101020900"
    let time="201507191254"
    let publicKey="http://open.weather.com.cn/data/?areaid=\(areaid)&type=forecast_v&date=\(time)&appid=\(appid)"

    let cPrivateKey=privateKey.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let cPublicKey=publicKey.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var cHMAC = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cPublicKey.bytes, Int(cPublicKey.length), cPrivateKey.bytes, Int(cPrivateKey.length), &cHMAC)

    let hexKeyString=NSMutableString(capacity: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    for byte in cHMAC{
        hexKeyString.appendFormat("%02hhx", byte)
    }
    println("hexKeyString:\(encryptedKey)")

    let binaryData = hexKeyString.dataFromHexadecimalString()
    let base64String = binaryData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
    println("base64String:\(base64String)")

    var urlEncodeKey=base64String!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
    println("urlEncodeKey:\(urlEncodeKey)")
    return urlEncodeMessage
}
```

*the outputs are:*

> *hexKeyString:d4433d42b1505c00a4aa80205171d0d04754d254*
>
> *base64String:1EM9QrFQXACkqoAgUXHQ0EdU0lQ=*
>
> *urlEncodeKey:1EM9QrFQXACkqoAgUXHQ0EdU0lQ=*

**PHP in Codecademy:**

```
echo urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', " http://open.weather.com.cn/data/?areaid=101020900&type=forecast_v&date=201507191254&appid=a1b2c34d5e", "ef7d6s0d", TRUE)));
```

*the output is:*

> A5O59Y%2BFbGjhVwaI9JNB7DkcX%2F4%3D      // the output is much like the
>   example in API, which I think maybe the right one.

So, how can I receive the right **urlEncodeKey** for my privateKey & publicKey like in PHP?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I've been fighting with the same problem since morning! Thanks for the solution Steve! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read more about cryptography and hashing. In your case, there's no public key, private key, ... SHA stands for *Secure hash algorithm* and what you're trying to get is *Hash based authentication code*. Check Wikipedia articles about [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hash-based_message_authentication_code&redirect=no), [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), [Public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), ... I strongly recommend to read more about it otherwise you can create more damage if you misunderstand it.

Back to your problem. It's in one character:

- Swift code - `let publicKey="http://open.weather.com.cn...`
- PHP code - `hash_hmac('sha1', " http://open.weather.com.cn...`

Do you see where the problem is? In your PHP code, there's one space  character just before `http`. This character is not in your Swift code.

Honestly, I didn't check your whole code, because I don't know why you're trying to convert it from hexadecimal string, etc. Used some parts only and rewrote it from scratch for you. Here's working example:

```
func URLEncodedKey() -> String? {
  let appid = "a1b2c34d5e"
  let time = "201507191254"
  let areaid = "101020900"

  let key = "ef7d6s0d"
  let string = " http://open.weather.com.cn/data/?areaid=\(areaid)&type=forecast_v&date=\(time)&appid=\(appid)"
  //            ^  <- in your PHP example, there's space

  guard let keyData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    stringData = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    outputData = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)) else {
    return nil
  }
  outputData.length = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)

  CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1),
    keyData.bytes, keyData.length,
    stringData.bytes, stringData.length,
    outputData.mutableBytes)

  return outputData
    .base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
    .stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
}
```

Return value is:

```
`Optional("A5O59Y+FbGjhVwaI9JNB7DkcX/4=")`
```

Which is what you get when you decode your PHP output.

Just replace `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` with any of the following character sets:

```
class func URLUserAllowedCharacterSet() -> NSCharacterSet    
class func URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet() -> NSCharacterSet
class func URLHostAllowedCharacterSet() -> NSCharacterSet    
class func URLPathAllowedCharacterSet() -> NSCharacterSet
class func URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet() -> NSCharacterSet
class func URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet() -> NSCharacterSet
```

Depends on your use case. IOW in which part of the URL your would like to use it.