# iOS Swift convert HEX string to Base64 with NO_WRAP option

Tags: ios, swift

Equivalent of Android's Base 64 NO_WRAP option in swift's Base 64?

In android:
hash = Base64.encodeToString(message.getBytes()), Base64.NO_WRAP);

See NO_WRAP option below:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

What's the equivalent in swift for iOS to convert a HEX String to Base 64 with the NO_WRAP option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the doc:

- [base64 encoding options](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata.base64encodingoptions)
- [base64 decoding options](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata.base64decodingoptions)

So just specify no option at all when encoding to avoid adding any line ending character, and specify `ignoreUnknownCharacters` when decoding to ignore line ending characters.

Step 1: [Hex String to Data is a separate StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26501276/1033581) (but you should avoid Hex String to begin with, it's a big waste of bytes!)

Step 2: Data to base64 Data or base64 String (choose one)

```
// By default, no line endings are inserted: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1412739-base64encodeddata
let encodedAsData = data.base64EncodedData()

// By default, no line endings are inserted: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1413546-base64encodedstring
let encodedAsString = data.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: and how to convert from HEX to Base 64?