# Converting hex string to data not returning readable output in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

The following snippet I used to convert Hex string to NSData. Here i ams ending text field input as 1234, the output supposed to be <1234> , instead am getting

> some : 20 bytes
>       - count : 20
>       ▿ pointer : 0x0000000283acc580
>         - pointerValue : 10799072640
>       ▿ bytes : 20 elements
>         - 0 : 53
>         - 1 : 54
>         - 2 : 0
>         - 3 : 0
>         - 4 : 0
>         - 5 : 0
>         - 6 : 0
>         - 7 : 0
>         - 8 : 0
>         - 9 : 0
>         - 10 : 0
>         - 11 : 0
>         - 12 : 0
>         - 13 : 0
>         - 14 : 0
>         - 15 : 0
>         - 16 : 0
>         - 17 : 0
>         - 18 : 0

```
  - 19 : 0



var command = inputTextField.text
        command = command?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

        let commandToSend = NSMutableData()
        var wholeByte = CUnsignedChar()

        var byte_char: [CChar] = [0, 0, 0]

        for i in 0..<command!.count/2{

            byte_char[0] = CChar((command! as NSString).character(at: i*2))
            byte_char[1] = CChar((command! as NSString).character(at: (i*2)+1))
            wholeByte = CUnsignedChar(strtoul(byte_char, nil, 16))
            commandToSend.append(&wholeByte, length: 1)

        }
```

Expected result : <1234>
with the same kind of snippet objetive c valid

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Why not just append a `<` and `>` to `command`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501276/converting-hex-string-to-nsdata-in-swift/26503955#26503955

Comment: your result seems correct to me. Two bytes `[18, 52]`.