# Unable to set correct device token from Objective-C to Klaviyo Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am integrating Klaviyo Swift SDK in out React Native Project which has Objective-C for iOS.

To integrate Swift sdk, I have written a package and through that I am setting push token to Klaviyo SDK.

But the resulting APN token is bad (this message I have received from Klaviyo push notification campaign).

I am using PushNotificationIOS to get device token in Javascript and I use this to send to package.

My token is:

```
let tokenString = "80263c753804d9356a12e47d3e3b64145bba8bf4b1d330cbf7d38dc4f60dc7c811f505086fc8b43b1cabc583724cd11ce98edfdf6cf8db44045ff092d232c35886a058710b3ae73bddda920de153a58a"
```

I have converted it to `Data` as Klaviyo SDK accepts in `Data` so I am doing:

```
Data(tokenString.utf8)
```

and internally Klaviyo Swift SDK does:

```
tokenData.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

and the resulting token is:

> 38303236336337353338303464393335366131326534376433653362363431343562626138626634623164333330636266376433386463346636306463376338313166353035303836666338623433623163616263353833373234636431316365393865646664663663663864623434303435666630393264323332633335383836613035383731306233616537336264646461393230646531353361353861

This result should match with tokenString.

Need help on this.

Comment: What is the resulting token supposed to be? Where's the Objective-C part of this question? All I see if Swift code.

Comment: In AppDelegate.m file under didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

We have

[RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501276/converting-hex-string-to-nsdata-in-swift for the needed way to convert your `tokenString` into `Data` such that the resulting token will match the original token string.

Comment: The app delegate method is already giving you `NSData`. Why do you convert that to a `String` and then back into `Data`? Why not directly pass the original data and skip all of the conversions?

Comment: I am not converting it to String. PushNotificationIOS provides me this token in JS code. I am using this token to set to Klaviyo SDK.

Klaviyo SDK is in Swift and I want to use functionality as per user functionality.

Comment: Then you need to use one of the answers in the link I provided to convert `tokenString` into `tokenData` instead of using `Data(tokenString.ut8)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the device token received from 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' and set it to the Klaviyo profile wherever you want to set it using the below:

```swift
Klaviyo.sharedInstance.addPushDeviceToken(deviceToken: {YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN})
```

With the above also connect your email ID so it will connect your email and device push token in the same profile.

After that, you can create a test user segment which includes your user in it and create the campaign to test push notifications.